# Creating a file path to a file, where the files name changes daily

Tags: c#, filepath

I am trying to get a file path to a file where the file name keep changing. So far, I have a file path to a particular log file named **18052015.log**. I am specifying the file name and extension, **18052015.log**.

```
string strFilePath = @"\\server-1\public\logs\18052015.log";
```

The file name matches a date. Each day a new file is generated. So, tomorrow there will be a file named **19052015.log**

The only file I'm interested in retrieving is the one named date.log as in **18052015.log** or **19052015.log**. I cannot use the option to just retrieve any log with a .log extension, as there are many other files in the same **logs** folder, all with the file extension **.log** e.g *AFile.log, BFile.log, 1File.log, 2File.log*. So, the following code doesn't help.

```
string[] files = Directory.GetFiles(strFilePath, "*.log", SearchOption.AllDirectories);
```

My question is, how, if the name of the file changes daily, can I retrieve that one log without specifying it's name?

Comment: What do you mean *"without specifying its name"*?

Comment: DateTime. you could use DateTime.Day, or DateTime.Month

Comment: @Yuval, what I mean is I need to retrieve this file automatically. Because the name changes daily, how do I get around this?

Comment: have a look at this [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9809266/network-folder-browser-service)

Comment: In java you can do (new Date).getDate()+"052015.log" to create a new string begining with current date.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're looking for `DateTime.Now` in a specified format:

```
string directoryPath = @"\\server-1\public\logs;"
string fullLogPath = string.Format(@"{0}\{1:ddMMyyyy}.log", directoryPath, DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: @Sayse He's trying to get a file with a specific filename, daily.

Answer (score 1):

To combine all solutions:

```
string fullFilename = Path.Combine( @"\\server-1\public\logs", string.Format("{0:ddMMyyyy}.log", myTime) );
```

And to correctly use Path.Combine instead of string'formatting around :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use [DateTime](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime(v=vs.110).aspx)

Here is a little example:

```
DateTime myTime = DateTime.Now;

string fileName = string.Format("{0}{1}{2}.log", myTime.Date, myTime.Month, myTime.Year);
```

DateTime.Now gives you the Time from your computer. then you can extract the Date, Month and Year from the Struct.